# Understanding Recursion C++

Tags: c++, recursion

```
.       *** *   |
***** * *** *** |
   *    *       |
 * * * ** **O** |
 *   *    *   * |
 ********** *** |
    * *       **|
**    * ** *    |
```

Hello guys, i'm just starting to learn recursion and i'm a little confused, I mean, I have this 8x16 maze (ignore the bars at the right side) the starting position of the maze is at 0,0 as you can tell in the maze, i have to get from there to the "O" point in a recursive way in c++, so far i have tried this

```
bool Laberinto::findPath(int x,int y){

//outside limits bounds
if(x  <  0 || x > nRows || y < 0 || y > nCol)
    return false;

//if goal
if(x == goalRow && y == goalCol){
    updateLab();
    return true;
}

//if obstacle
if(matrix[x][y] == '*' || matrix[x][y] == 'X'){
    return false;
}

matrix[x][y] = '.';
updateLab();

//North checking
if(findPath(x-1,y) == true){
    return true;
}
//East checking
if(findPath(x,y+1) == true){
    return true;
}
//South checking
if(findPath(x+1,y) == true){
    return true;
}
//West checking
if(findPath(x,y-1) == true){
    return true;
}

matrix[x][y] = 'X';
updateLab();
return false;

}
```

updateLab() just prints the labyrinth, the thing is that it goes to the east side till it finds an obstacle then goes once to the south side and stays up there until it crashes, but since i'm just starting to learn about recursion I don't see where my error is happening

```
........*** *   |
***** *.*** *** |
   *    *       |
 * * * ** **O** |
 *   *    *   * |
 ********** *** |
    * *       **|
**    * ** *    |
```

Comment: Where do `goalCol` and `goalRow` come from?

Comment: Start by running in a debugger to catch the crash in action, and learn where in your code it happens.

Comment: Your problem isn't recursion, that's fairly trivial, I suggest your concern has you focused on the wrong thing.  Just debug your code.  You most likely crash when you blow the stack due to the recursion.

Comment: You don't even need a debugger, you can follow your logic and trace the path by hand. You go east (because you can't go north) until you hit a wall. South is the first path that isn't blocked. Then north is the first path that isn't blocked. Then south is the first path that isn't blocked. And now you realize that you're stuck. Around the corner, a hungry grue has caught your scent...

Comment: goalCol and goalRow is where the O is located

Answer (score 3):

You need to include code to avoid travelling on a path you've already been.

```
if(matrix[x][y] == '.') /*....*/
```

What's probably happening is you're getting stuck in those two dots that are north and south of each other, because your code gets into an infinite loop moving north and south over and over.

Comment: What happens if it goes in some direction (a wrong one) and then it has to go back to keep checking the maze?

Comment: @Nadir It's recursive, so the stack should eventually pop back without needing to worry. But the user is getting a Stack Overflow because they're moving up and down over and over, entering new stack frames each time, until the program crashes.

Comment: You are totally right! i'm gonna try to implement this, thank you so much!